# Vary time between tasks according to wave function

Tags: python, sleep, frequency, waveform

I need to run `X` amount of tasks in a day, and I need the frequency of the tasks to vary according to a wave function (with a period of `2pi/24`, or with one peak per day and horizontal shift of `2pi/3.5` - I need to find the amplitude/vertical shift).

So I have the total daily tasks I want to run and I need to know how much time to sleep between them, according to time of day - how can I get to that equation? Can this be achieved in a simpler manner?

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

def get_daily_tasks(...):
  ...

def run_task(...):
  ...

def main(): # to be run daily
  num_tasks = get_daily_tasks(...)
  for _ in range(num_tasks):
    run_task(...)
    sleep_timer = sleep_timer(num_tasks, datetime.now())  # This is what I need to find
    sleep(sleep_timer)
```

Comment: This sounds more like a mathematical problem than a programming problem.